# I have a question with my discord bot Kick system

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, searchkick

I need to make that not everyone can kick members, but only who have permissions
Here is my kick system-

```
client.on('message', message => {

    if (!message.guild) return;


    if (message.content.startsWith('+kick')) {

      const user = message.mentions.users.first();

      if (user) {

        const member = message.guild.members.resolve(user);

        if (member) {

          member
            .kick({
              reason: 'They were bad!',
            })
            .then(() => {

              message.channel.send(`Successfully kicked ${user.tag}`);
            })
            .catch(err => {

              message.channel.send('I was unable to kick the member');

              console.error(err);
            });
        } else {

          message.channel.send("That user isn't in this guild!");
        }
      } else {

        message.channel.send("You didn't mention the user to kick!");
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Use `member.permissions.has()`. From docs: https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/permissions.html#checking-member-permissions

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`message.mentions.members.first()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/MessageMentions?scrollTo=members) to skip a step and simplify your code somewhat.

As mentioned above, you'll want to use [`member.permissions.has()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=has) to check if a member has the `MANAGE_MEMBERS` permission, or whatever other permission you want to check for. (See [`Permissions.FLAGS`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS))

Also, consider moving away from using message-based commands, if possible. For a small personal bot, it's not really an issue, but Discord is really pushing the new `Interactions` (aka slash commands) system, which you can read more about [here](https://discordjs.guide/interactions/slash-commands.html) (discord.js guide) and [here](https://discord.com/blog/slash-commands-are-here) (official, discord.com).

Answer (score -2):

in order to make only mods use a command I recommend you using `message.member.permissions.has()` which allows the bot to check if the person who ran the command has a certain permission in the guild or not. Then to return, if the person doesn't have permission, you can use it in an `if` statement like that:

```js
if (!message.member.permissions.has("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
    return message.reply({content: `You need permissions to use command`})
}
```

And of course you can always add in your `messageCreate` event a userPermissions to add on the top of your command.

So the event file would have:

```js
if (!message.member.permissions.has(<command>.userPermissions || [])) return message.channel.send({content: 'You need permissions to run this command'})
```

then you can just add in your command under name or description `userPermissions: ['KICK_MEMBERS'],`
This is the easiest way to handle user permissions

Comment: Add details to your answer and explain how it works, don't just dump code

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: is this better?